# Unable to retrieve the class name of any parent element fails or returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unable to retrieve the class name of any parent element fails or returns undefined:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click','.addfile', function() {
    // need to be dinamicaly
    var Target = $(this).parents('div').find('[class^="file-plugin-"]');
    Target = Target.attr('class');
    console.log(Target);
    var Target = $(this).closest('div').find('[class^="file-plugin-"]');
    Target = Target.attr('class');
    console.log(Target);
    var Target = $(this).parentsUntil('[class^="file-plugin-"]');
    Target = Target.attr('class');
    console.log(Target);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap1">
    <div class="other class file-plugin-1">
        <div class="wrap2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button type="button" class="remfile">Remove</button>
                <button type="button" class="addfile">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i need get: "file-plugin-1" in a var.

Comment: do you want to get `file-plugin-1` in three `console.log`?

Comment: @david i add three example of what I have tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using class^="

If you look at the documentation, you will see if it is Attribute Starts With Selector `[name^=”value”]`

That means the attribute needs to be

```
class="value-abc"
```

So it is not matching your case because the string is not at the very beginning. You would need to use Attribute Contains Selector `[name*=”value”]`

The other issue is closest will grab the wrapping div and the div you are looking for is still a grand parent of that div.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click','.addfile', function() {
    var elm = $(this).closest('[class*="file-plugin-"]');
    console.log(elm.attr("class"));
    console.log(elm.attr("class").match(/file-plugin-\d+/)[0])

    // how I would do it
    var elem = $(this).closest('[data-index]');
    console.log(elem.data("index"))
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap1">
    <div class="other class file-plugin-1" data-index="1">
        <div class="wrap2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button type="button" class="remfile">Remove</button>
                <button type="button" class="addfile">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i need get the element near with: `file-plugin-` can have element with other similar classes: "file-plugin-1", "file-plugin-2"

Comment: @walternuñez which is what `*=` would do. If you used a common class on the elements, than you could just reference the class  name and it would be more efficient.

Comment: ok but i only need get the class name as string= "file-plugin-1" for this element, but if the element have other class name instead: file-plugin-2 i need get this new. not the entirely element

Comment: This is why you should use Data Attributes, would make your life so much easier.

Comment: I can not depend on data attribute let's say that the designer and the person who reviews the html code will not support me added data attribute in this part of the pluggin

Comment: Designers should not rule a developers life. If that happens than it causes code to be more complex. Developers and designers need to learn how to work together so code does not need to be horrible. Works the same way with product management and customers. Tell the designer to add things so code is easier and faster to maintain.

Comment: @epascarello `match(/\bfile-plugin-\d+/)` please :)

Comment: @Tibrogargan glad you think it should be like that, I think it is overkill.

Comment: It's your answer.  Problem is you also match classes that have `file-plugin-` contained in them

Comment: @Tibrogargan okay, but the example does not have that problem. I am working with that it has... and it would also break if there was another class that was like `file-plugin-123-foobar`.

Comment: True. I guess to my mind it was implied by the use of the "starts with" selector

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to find elements class starting with certain text

```
$(document).on('click','.addfile', function() {
   var Target = $(this).parents().filter((i, ele)=>ele.className.match(/\bfile-plugin-/)).attr('class')
    console.log(Target);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the class of the div you are after literally does not **start** with `"file-plugin-"`, it just contains it.  You need to examine the class attribute manually, JQuery does not help with this much (that I know of).

Something like this should work:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click','.addfile', function() {
   // need to be dinamicaly
    var target = $(this).parents("div").filter((_, div) => -1 != div.className.indexOf('file-plugin-'));
    // console.log(target[0]);
    // Or using the "contains" selector (credit to @epascarello)
    target = $(this).parents("div[class*=file-plugin-]");
    var string = target.attr("class").split(" ").filter( clazz => clazz.startsWith('file-plugin-'))[0];
    console.log(string);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap1">
    <div class="other class file-plugin-1">
        <div class="wrap2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button type="button" class="remfile">Remove</button>
                <button type="button" class="addfile">Add</button>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok but i only need get the class name as string= "file-plugin-1" for this element, but if the element have other class name instead: file-plugin-2 i need get this new. not the entirely element

Comment: Made a change that does that